# selection of checkbox or radio button

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable

How we can change the jtable column , on the selection of the checkbox .Suppose i have two checkbox date, age and on the selection of date the jtable must show column date and on the selection of age it must show age .

thanks

Comment: try to post the `code` you have tried so far please..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How we can change the jtable column , on the selection of the checkbox
>   .Suppose i have two checkbox date, age and on the selection of date
>   the jtable must show column date and on the selection of age it must
>   show age .

- [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) has interface to [TableColumnModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html).
- Add an [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) or [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to `JCheckBox`.
- On [SELECTED](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#SELECTED) event from `ItemListener` call [JTable#addColumn()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#addColumn-javax.swing.table.TableColumn-), on [DESELECTED](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#DESELECTED) event call [JTable#removeColumn()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn-javax.swing.table.TableColumn-)
- Colums are removed only from table's ***view***, value is still present in the [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)

Comment: i am new to the java can you explain by a giving a example